# Can <h2> have React's onLoad?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make a calendar where, once the page loads, it has already gone through a function to get the current month. This is by using HTML format within React's JS file.

```js
<h2 onLoad={curMonth}></h2>
```

I have `curMonth` being imported from a different file:

```js
import { curMonth } from '../../calendar';
```

I will also include the function made, in case it would be some help to understand:

```js
function curMonth() {
    let monthName = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
    let today = new Date();
    let month = today.getMonth();
    let listedMonth = document.querySelector(".calendar h2");
    listedMonth.textContent = monthName[month];
}


export { curMonth };
```

Previously, I had a default set to `<h2>September</h2>`, but it continued to stay "September" after the load was complete too, and I would also like for it to be the current month. Currently, it is at `<h2 onLoad={curMonth}></h2>` but left empty after load.

I followed these two guides: [react.dev](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/components/common#mouseevent-handler) and [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_events.asp)

Is it that `<h2>` should not include the onLoad function? What is the reason why the function is not run on load?

Comment: Should not it be curMonth()?

Comment: One of the sources I followed was [this](https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_events.asp), but I have not tried the parenthesis so I guess I can do that now! @orabis

Comment: But wouldn't it make more sense to put the result in the h2 like this? `<h2>{curMonth()}</h2>` and then let the function just return the current month, like this: `return "December"`. That way you don't need the `querySelector`

Comment: Would that mean I should just leave it to the function to dive deeper into the body to find `h2`? @Kokodoko

Comment: You should use react variables to put data in the DOM, instead of using `querySelector`, see my edited comment.

Comment: Don't do onLoad={x()}. This is plain bad code and will break as soon as react rerenders. Instead use @Konrad's solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more react way:

```
function curMonth() {
    let monthName = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
    let today = new Date();
    let month = today.getMonth();
    return monthName[month];
}
```

```
<h2>{curMonth()}</h2>
```